# Submit a form whose inner text is in xmlHttp.responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts

I have made a struts application.
A front Page is jsp which has a form and an image.
If you enter any data in a field and click the image, it will search for the details for that particular value and print it in a div on the same page.
The returned data is in the form of table with checkboxes and the values.And this table format lies in another jsp page.
I did that using `Ajax` to get all the values and show it on the same page so I need not refresh all the time.

```
`document.getElementById("prtCnt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`


where "prnCnt" is the Id of that div.
```

Now I want to check some checkboxes and submit the whole form (with already existing fields on form and the table values with checked boxes ).

how should I be able to do that?

abc.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
   <%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html" prefix="html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="ajaxjs.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
function getvalue() {
    var value = document.getElementById("client").value;
    loadContent(value);
}
</script>
<body>
<html:form action="AjaxAction.do" >
    <html:text property="client"  value="ankit"  styleId="client" /> <img
        style="cursor: hand" id="search" src="images/1search.gif"  width="15"
        height="15" border="0" onclick="getvalue()">
     </html:form>
 <div id="prtCnt"></div>
 </body>

</html>`
```

ajaxjs.js

`var xmlhttp;
    function loadContent(value)
    {
     xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
      if (xmlhttp==null)
      {
       alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
       return;
      }
    url="AjaxAction.do?client="+value;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=getOutput;
    xmlhttp.open("post",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
    function getOutput()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
      {
          alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      document.getElementById("prtCnt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
       return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
          return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
     return null;
    }`

tableshow.jsp

```
enter code here

<%@page import="com.ajax.AjaxForm"%>
<%
AjaxForm aj = (AjaxForm) request.getAttribute("bean");
%>
<html>
<body>
<table width="99%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr align="left" class="tableheader">
<td width="5%">CheckBox</td>
    <td width="10%">Account Number</td>
    <td width="12%">Tax Form ID</td>
    <td width="12%">Account Name</td>
    <td width="12%">Product</td>
    <td width="12%">Bank ID</td>
    <td width="12%">Client ID [ECI]</td>
    <td width="10%">Relationship type</td>
    <td width="5%">LOB</td>
    <td width="10%">Account Status</td>
</tr>
<tr class="GridRow">
<td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" name="check"> </td>
    <td width="10%"><a href=""><%=aj.getDummy()%></a>
    </td>
    <td width="12%"><%=aj.getClient()%></td>
    <td width="12%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
    <td width="12%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
    <td width="12%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
    <td width="12%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
    <td width="10%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
    <td width="5%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
    <td width="10%"><%=aj.getDummy()%></td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

`

AjaxAction.java

```
package com.ajax;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class AjaxAction extends Action {
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm actionForm,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("from action");
    AjaxForm aj = (AjaxForm) actionForm;
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("client"));
    if(aj.getClient()!=null){}
    else
        aj.setClient("ankit");
    //aj.setClient(request.getParameter("client"));

    System.out.println(aj.getClient()+"1111111111111111111111111111111");
    if (aj.getClient().equals("ankit"))
        aj.setDummy("Dummy Value for ankit");
    else if (aj.getClient().equals("arpit"))
        aj.setDummy("Dummy Value for arpit"); 
    else if (aj.getClient().equals("rohit"))
        aj.setDummy("Dummy Value for rohit");
    else{
        aj.setClient("soni");
        aj.setDummy("Dummy Value for soni");
    }
    System.out.println("after setting");
    System.out.println(aj.getClient());
    System.out.println(aj.getDummy());
    request.setAttribute("bean", aj);
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us as well with some data? How does the request/response look like? What is the html/js code of page?